# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL issue with markdown to HTML converter

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, markdown

I'm using [markdown-editor](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor), but having some issues when rendering markdown back to HTML using [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

my code for marked.js is

```
<script>
        var myString = "${post.postBody}";
        var newString =myString.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
        document.getElementById('entry-content').innerHTML =
        marked(newString);
  </script>
```

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the string value becomes like

[image: Imgage]

how can I escape those <kbd>Enter</kbd> issues.

Comment: When you render `marked.js`, `${post.postBody}` has a newline inside and it renders a string with newline inside. Javascript strings don't support newlines, you need to escape them with `\n`.

Comment: What kind of server side language expands ${post.postBody}  ? That is key to answering the question and you should probably update the text and tags to reflect that.

Comment: @Stefan server side is Spring MVC I've updated tag

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that `${post.postBody}` has been replaced by something else.

That something else includes line breaks.

Line breaks are not permitted in JavaScript string literals.

You need to fix whatever that is so that it outputs a valid JavaScript string literal. Usually, a JSON encoder will do the job for that task.

Comment: ${post.postBody} is expression language in jsp page which loads data from server.

Comment: @ArshadAli — and that data includes line breaks, which aren't allowed … I'll stop simply repeating myself now.